# Radare2 - Saving information/metadata from a debugging session

Tags: debugging, radare2

I'd like to know how I can save/restore comments or possibly other metadata during a debugging session.

I know how to save this data when running radare without the `-d` flag but I often need to debug the binary and would like a way to save *at least* the comments I made during this.

I know about the `Ps` `Po` commands but this is what radare2 tells me

```
[0x7ff33eba18a0]> Ps xxx
radare2 does not support projects on debugged bins.
Cannot save project.
```

I am using version:

```
> r2 -v
radare2 5.6.8 0 @ linux-x86-64 git.
commit: 5.6.8 build: 2022-06-22__12:33:33
```

Any help or other way of achieving this is also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projects has been disabled in debugger mode because not all metadata is rebased when aslr is involved which may result on confusing analysis/comments information. If you disable aslr, or your target is always loading in the same place you can do a couple of things:

- `Ps saving@e:cfg.debug=false`

or just save the comments into a file:

- `CC* > comments.r2`

you can reload the script with the `. comments.r2` or starting the session with `r2 -i comments.r2 ...` to get the comment lines loaded into the session.

Same goes for all the analysis information. if you append `*` to any command you get the output in r2 commands script.

Comment: Can aslr be disabled on a per-binary basis? I think gdb can do it but i am not sure.